# How do I optimize Windows disk I/O for high-latency throughput?

Tags: hard-drive, performance, latency, windows-server-2012-r2, throughput

Let's say there are 25 processes each which want to read and index a large (say, 1GB) file.
The hard drive may be capable of ~100MB/sec throughput, but the head movement and rotational latency involved in moving between such processes is significant so may reduce throughput to 5MB/sec, or just 5% of the conventional drive's throughput capability.

Were the hard drive to read a large amount of data (say, 32MB) or read whatever it can for a long time (say, 200ms) before moving onto the next process, file IO could approach the full throughput of the drive at the expense of latency.

Does Windows have such a facility for accomplishing this goal in cases where latency takes a back seat to throughput?

[image]

Comment: check the tool DiskSpd: http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2014/10/13/diskspd-powershell-and-storage-performance-measuring-iops-throughput-and-latency-for-both-local-disks-and-smb-file-shares.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is what the [NCQ protocol](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Command_Queuing) is for. A drive that supports NCQ looks at all of the incoming commands and reorders them to service them more efficiently (and essentially, *reordering* the commands is what you're asking about).

That said, I see in your example you have a disk queue depth of 27, so we're well past the help of even NCQ. This is a problem for RAID (possibly coupled with faster physical storage).

There *are* storage parameters that can be adjusted in Windows, particularly those related to caching behavior, but that's not going to help enough in your case.

Comment: I think of NCQ as more for helping small, near random I/Os like database access. The drive involved does have NCQ and it probably helps a bit, bit I think this situation is more about tuning the Windows I/O scheduler.
Linux allows me to choose I/O schedulers (deadline, CFQ...), but in fairness none of them would be much better than Windows' default in this case.

Comment: Additionally NCQ is in use by the drive whose performance is tested in the original question, still yielding less than 5% of the maximum throughput.